# Issue with custom capitalize String method, jQuery and Select2

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, jquery-select2

I am getting some trouble with jQuery and Select2.

I created a function for the String prototype to capitalize it.
On the other hand, I am using jQuery 1.11.0 and Select2 3.4.5 and when i click on the Select2, I got an error because the capitalize method is called on a non-string object:

> Unable to capitalize non-string value.
>
> ```
> <div id="select2-drop" class="select2-drop select2-display-none select2-with-searchbox select2-drop-auto-width" style="left: 813.5px; width: 380px; top: 777px; bottom: auto;">
> ```
>
> printStackTrace.implementation.prototype.createException@http://my.domain.com/js/stacktrace.js:56
>   printStackTrace.implementation.prototype.run@http://my.domain.com/js/stacktrace.js:43
>   printStackTrace@http://my.domain.com/js/stacktrace.js:30
>   String.prototype.capitalize@http://my.domain.com/js/orpheus.js:101
>   jQuery.access@http://my.domain.com/js/jquery.js:4122
>   jQuery.access@http://my.domain.com/js/jquery.js:4094
>   .css@http://my.domain.com/js/jquery.js:6911
>   AbstractSelect2<.positionDropdown@http://my.domain.com/js/select2/select2.js:1231
>   AbstractSelect2<.opening@http://my.domain.com/js/select2/select2.js:1322
>   SingleSelect2<.opening@http://my.domain.com/js/select2/select2.js:1840
>   AbstractSelect2<.open@http://my.domain.com/js/select2/select2.js:1265
>   SingleSelect2<.initContainer/<@http://my.domain.com/js/select2/select2.js:2039
>   AbstractSelect2<.bind/<@http://my.domain.com/js/select2/select2.js:651
>   jQuery.event.dispatch@http://my.domain.com/js/jquery.js:4624
>   jQuery.event.add/elemData.handle@http://my.domain.com/js/jquery.js:4292

I got the stacktrace with the stacktrace.js lib.
orpheus.js is my JS file containing the capitalize method (modified for the tests):

```
String.prototype.capitalize = function () {
    if( typeof this != "string" ) {
        console.log("Unable to capitalize non-string value.");
        console.log(this);
        console.log(printStackTrace().join("\n"));
        return this;
    }
    return this.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + this.slice(1).toLowerCase();
};
```

Comment: Why do you need to check for string here as anyway this `capitalyze` method could only be called on string otherwise generating an error. Could you replicate your issue somewhere online?

Answer (score 0):

Using select2, i wanted to add a class to the dropdown but i used the dropdownCss instead of dropdownCssClass, changing it fixes the issue.
But the real problem is why jQuery calls capitalize method on non string object if i use a string instead of an object/function. This is really weird.